# Allocate a 2D vector in unified memory CUDA C/C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, cuda, 2d

So I need to create a matrix with different row lengths, and this is how it looks like in normal C/C++

```
int** MpesosT = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        MpesosT[i] = (int*)malloc(vecinosT[i] * sizeof(int));
    }
```

However, I don't know how to do this using the CUDA function to allocate memory:

```
int* Vector;    cudaMallocManaged(&Vector, VectorSize* sizeof(int));
```

I can't just use a vector of size N*N or something, because every row has a different size, so how could I do that?

Comment: This is not how you should do it in C++. In C++ you should not use `malloc`, but `new` instead, and really you shouldn't do manual allocation in the first place. Instead use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Took a couple of hours, but I found the way to do it. In case anyone has the same problem:

```
double** Matrix;
cudaMallocManaged((double***)&Matrix, N * sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cudaMallocManaged((double**)&Matrix[i], rowlength[i] * sizeof(double));
}
```

This way, every row has a different length

Comment: In your question you mention shared memory. This isn't allocation in shared memory

Comment: I don't know about CUDA, but the explicit casts are pointless. You can remove `(double***)` and `(double**)` without affecting the result. Having unnecessary casts is dangerous as you might accidentally cast to something unintended. For the same reason C style casts are bad, you should always use the appropriate cast out of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, etc. to make your intentions clear and avoid accidental miscasts (the C style cast allow basically any cast for pointers, even e.g. removing `const`). `sizeof` can also be made safer by using `sizeof(*Matrix)` and `sizeof(*Matrix[i])`.

Comment: The CUDA style guide strongly discourages 2D array allocation, you should strongly consider allocating 1D arrays that use 2D index calculations instead